# Bahamian fruit tree identification

Tags: identification, fruit-trees, tropical

A Bahamian friend (living on the island of Andros) has found the following fruit tree growing in his garden. The fruit looks vaguely avicadoish, but with many seeds, more like a melon or gourd. From the pictures, it looks like the fruit opens up to release the seeds when it's ripe (dehiscence).

The locals have never seen this species before. Any idea what this could be?

[image: A picture of some avocado-like fruit.]

[image: A picture of a tropical tree.]

Comment: At first glance it looks like one of the many variants of Guava grown in sub-tropical regions all across the world and this might have been self seeded from a shop-bought fruit/berry. Other members might have a more accurate diagnosis however, hence why my notes are only as a comment rather than a distinct answer?